# Why doesn't queryRaw method in GreenDao return a lazy list?

Tags: android, greendao

queryRaw returns a normal list! But, this isn't good for many records and I need lazy list.

So, How can get a lazy list from queryRaw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added a new method called queryRawCreate, which returns a Query object. Using the query, you can obtain a LazyList now. It's pushed to GitHub. You will need to use the source version until the next release.

Relevant change:
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/commit/16705725231219907c1c0b42f3ba653833de7230

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific needs, it might work out using a standard [QueryBuilder](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/). Check out WhereCondition.StringCondition. Using this you can pass any SQL fragments for the WHERE clause to the query builder.

Comment: I used to QueryBuilder, but it's not useful for me; because my query is a join between two tables and QueryBuilder can't do it. I need use QueryRaw. And QueryRaw doesn't return lazy list.